# Debian server on a flash drive

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, usb-flash-drive

I want to make an flash drive that when you put it into an computer it will boot the debian up and you can ssh into it. I don't want to boot into it, because I sometimes don't have a lot of time or i just have to stay into windows or other os. Like the shark jack from hak5.  I just want to have Linux where I go and I found a computer.

Comment: I think you will find it to be very slow. USB Flash Drives are slow and often unreliable. Just when you need it, the Flash drive may expire.

Comment: That's a nice idea. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Show us your research.

Comment: Shark jack is a computer (howbeit small), not a flash drive.  You can't make a flash drive that boots an OS without booting the OS.  A flash drive is not a computer.